# Creating a Map in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

```
<xsl:variable name="map">
   <map>
        <item key="Name" value="John"/>
        <item key="Address" value="Un_Known"/>
        <item key="Phone" value="(878)876678"/>
        <item key="Last Name" value="Verner"/>
    </map>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select "$map/map/item">
   <xsl:if test="./@key = $input">
      <!-- cool user is asking for something know .. do something fancy -->
   </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each>
```

I want to declare a map like structure in my XSLT and then want to access it. Apparently, I would like not to use extra name spaces so using exsl:node-set is not the solutions I am looking for right-now.

I am using XSLT 1.0 Saxon.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do ?

Thanks
Karephul

---

All the below mentioned answers are correct and valid. We finally decided to use the "exsl:node-set"

### Thanks for your suggestions ..

Comment: Why do you not want to use extra namespaces? Do you mean that you don't want to use extensions?

Comment: Franky speaking - I have not done research to find out if that will hurt performance & if I am allowed to add new namespace in the xslt I am modifying.

Comment: Namespaces will not necessarily hurt performance, and they do not necessarily mean that it will load any additional code/modules. You can use namespaces to simply uniquely qualify your XML and either embed it within your XSLT or load it from an external file, as @LarsH suggests.

Comment: It would be silly for someone to forbid you to use additional namespaces, for their own sake. That would be like forbidding comments or new variables. However I could understand if someone wanted to avoid the portability issues of using an extension function. In any case, there is no need to use `node-set()`, as shown by my and Mads' answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include extra XML information, like your `<map>` directly in your XSLT. That XML data will need to be bound to a namespace (other than the XSLT namespace), but it can be any namespace.

You can access the data within the XSLT by using the `document()` function with an empty string, which will load the XSLT document.

Incidentally, you can eliminate the need for the `<xsl:if>` by using a predicate filter on the XPath of your `xsl:for-each` select.

For instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:my="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146687/creating-a-map-in-xlst">

    <xsl:param name="input" />

    <my:map >
        <item key="Name" value="John"/>
        <item key="Address" value="Un_Known"/>
        <item key="Phone" value="(878)876678"/>
        <item key="Last Name" value="Verner"/>
    </my:map>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:map/item[@key=$input]">
                <!-- cool user is asking for something know .. do something fancy -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good answer - I didn't think about using `document('')`.

Comment: if this XSLT is being referred from another XSLT .. and similarly there are 100's of XSLT(s) being referred .. that document('') which load the currently executing xslt or the all the XSLT's ? how about performance ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Saxon, then it is very hard to see why you are still using XSLT 1.0. This kind of thing (and many other things) are much easier in XSLT 2.0 - it's time you moved forward.

Comment: @OP - XSLT 2.0 is very backward-compatible with 1.0, so there is little reason to be concerned about breaking existing stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `node-set()` extension function, you can put your `<map>` data in a separate XML file, e.g. `map.xml`. Then access that file from your stylesheet using `document('map.xml')`. You can then access the contents of the map using XPath expressions, as you showed above.

Answer (score 1):

You got three very good answers.

**Here is another, that demonstrates how to use keys to access a lookup table** (which in practical cases would reside in a separate XML document):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pInput" select="'Phone'"/>
   <my:map>
        <item key="Name" value="John"/>
        <item key="Address" value="Un_Known"/>
        <item key="Phone" value="(878)876678"/>
        <item key="Last Name" value="Verner"/>
    </my:map>

 <xsl:key name="kLookup" match="item/@value" use="../@key"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
       <xsl:value-of select="key('kLookup', $pInput)"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
(878)876678
```

---

**In XSLT 2.0 the `xsl:for-each` isn't needed**, because the **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-key)** function accepts a third argument that specifies the document to be indexed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pInput" select="'Phone'"/>
   <my:map>
        <item key="Name" value="John"/>
        <item key="Address" value="Un_Known"/>
        <item key="Phone" value="(878)876678"/>
        <item key="Last Name" value="Verner"/>
    </my:map>

 <xsl:key name="kLookup" match="item/@value" use="../@key"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="key('kLookup', $pInput, document(''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```